# Changing the angle of a D3 doughnut chart to 180

Tags: d3.js

I need to make my doughnut chart a horizontal graph like in this image >

[image]

this is the code that i use for other doughnut charts

```
   var dataset = {
        hddrives: [total - value, value],
    };

    var width = 460,
        height = 300,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range([secondColor, mainColor]);


    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .sort(null);



    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(radius - 100)
        .outerRadius(radius - 70);

    var svg = d3.select(divName).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

    //Draw the Circle
    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", 0)
        .attr("cy", 0)
        .attr("r", 65)
        .attr("fill", "#F6FBF3");

    var path = svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(pie(dataset.hddrives))
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "arc")
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr("d", arc);
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("dy", "0em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "inside")
        .attr("font-size", "30px")
        .text(function (d) { return value; });
    svg.append("text")
        .attr("dy", "1.5em")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "data")
        .text(function (d) { return nomeGtin; });
}
```

I tried messing around with the attr values and the arc value, but without success, any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks

Comment: If you want to use a perfectly straight rectangle with no curve, then using an arc isn't going to work - you are better off using `d3.stack` for a single stacked bar chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't much of a donut chart, it's now a stacked bar chart (with a single bar).  The `pie` and `arc` helpers aren't much help for that, they are concerned with calculating angles and circular things; you are now dealing with rectangles.  `d3.stack` could help, but is probably overkill.  Here's a quicky where I've just done the math (ie positioning) myself:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@3.5.17" data-semver="3.5.17" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
    
      var width = 500,
          height = 200,
          w = 300,
          h = 100;
    
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

      var total = 0,
          l = 0,
          // fake random data
          raw = d3.range(5).map(function(d){
            var v = Math.random() * 10;
            total += v;
            return v;
          }),
          // calculate percents and cumulative position
          data = raw.map(function(d){
            var rv = {
              v: d,
              l: l,
              p: d/total
            }
            l += rv.p;
            return rv;
          });

      // scale and color
      var s = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, w])
        .domain([0, 1]),
        c = d3.scale.category20();

      svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function(d){
          return s(d.l) + width/2 - w/2; // place based on cumulative
        })
        .attr('width', function(d){
          return s(d.p); // width from scale
        })
        .attr('height', h)
        .attr('y', height/2 - h/2)
        .style('fill', function(d,i){
          return c(i);
        })
        .style('stroke', 'white')
        .style('stroke-width', '2px');
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```